# how to make View of create type with two model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view bind with two models ...so I choose `ViewModel` method to bind two models with a view ...but I am facing problem to create a view of `Create` type  ...but I am facing error ...FeedbackMix is ViewModel here...I have to pass query object for displaying something in the layout at the same time I have to make Create type view page ...
**ERROR:**

> CS1061: 'FeedbackMixModel' does not contain a definition for 'Message' and no extension method 'Message' accepting a first argument of type 'FeedbackMixModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var msg= db.Messages.ToList();
    var feed = db.Feedbacks.ToList();
    FeedbackMixModel vm = new FeedbackMixModel();
    vm.allfeedbacks = feed;
   //this is also create type view 
    return View(vm);
}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.FeedbackMixModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    ....
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class FeedbackMixModel
{
    public List<UserManager> allUserManagers { get; set; }
    public List<Feedback> allfeedbacks { get; set; }
    public List<Package> allpackages { get; set; }
    public List<Messages> allmessages { get; set; }
}
```

**ERROR LINE**

> Line 16: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward...in your `FeedbackMixModel` you don't have a `Message` property or method

Comment: yep i know i pasted this code so that you people can understand easily ,,,i explain what exactly i want..you people can please paste your code how can i create view of type Create from this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a property on your `FeedbackViewModel` called `Message`, which your `LabelFor()` helper is expecting so it doesn't know how to bind this :

```
public  class FeedbackMixModel
{
    public List<UserManager> allUserManagers { get; set; }
    public List<Feedback> allfeedbacks { get; set; }
    public List<Package> allpackages { get; set; }
    public List<Messages> allmessages { get; set; }

    // No property named Message here
}
```

If you want to have something like this, you'll need to add the property and populate it prior to passing it to the Model.

Are you sure that you aren't meaning to have a loop to iterate through your `allMessages` property and access this from those individual elements?

```
<h4>Messages</h4>
<hr />
@foreach(var message in Model.allMessages)
{
    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(message => message.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.EditorFor(message => message.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(message=> message.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: for what i use FOrEach loop it is just Create type View.And the layout used by this view need a query object ..so i have to use ViewModel  because this is create type view of  table1(Package class) and also at the same time i have to pass query object of another table say table2(notification class) for layout to display somthing through partial view..i hope  you understand my problem..actually i dont know how to create create type view from view model...